# Gulp Not working with Magento2

Tags: magento2.2.2, less, less-css

unfortunately I am new to Gulp, and I really need it to debug and sourcemapping, so to better understand less too, which is also quite new for me.

Anyway everything in place, I deploy trough usual `bin/magento` since the `gulp exec` and `gulp deploy` give me errors.

but it seems that `gulp less --theme --map` does not produce any less or map file, where they should be? If I use web inspector on Safari 11 it still give me the style-l.css and style-m.css and not the less behind them,

I read on another tread to cmd-click should bring me to the less, but it doesn't

what am I do it wrong?

Comment: can you share your website URL?

Comment: Meanwhile check this [link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-video-introduction-for-using-gulp-in-frontend), for more understanding of where you are lacking something.

Comment: Hello, I could ngrok the local dev but I would prefere not to, the link you gave is like so many other link explaining the basics, I do arrive there, but no result seems to be produced, how exactly I am sure I am producing the map files? they should be in pub/static/frontend/VENDOR/Theme/en_US/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end that was my intl.so not loading properly, I had to reinstall the entire php library, and then M2 all over again, and give up on Gulp and start anew with Grunt, Working good right now